# Using multiple checkboxes, all made by a javascript function, with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, checkbox

A function uses Google Maps API results to create a list of places (hotels etc.) besides each one there is a checkbox:

```
if(place['rating']) {
    LocationName = place['name'];
    LocationString += `<div class="input-group" id="Location-checkbox-${[i]}">
                                <span value=${[i]} class="input-group-addon">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" 
    id="checkboxes" aria-label="..." onclick="chooseSelection(${[i]})">
                                </span>
                                <li id="Location-${[i]}" class="list-group- 
    item"><strong id="locationName-${[i]}">${LocationName}</strong><br>`;
if(place['rating']) {
    var LocationRating = place['rating'];
    LocationString += `rating: <span 
    id="locationRating-${[i]}">${LocationRating}</span><br>`;
    } else {
    var LocationRating = 'This place has no rating';
    LocationString += LocationRating;
    }

    if(place['user_ratings_total']) {
        var LocationUsers = place['user_ratings_total'];
        LocationString += `based on ${LocationUsers} reviews</li></div>`;
        } else {
        var LocationUsers = '</li></div>';
        LocationString += LocationUsers;
        }

        htmlString += LocationString;
```

I then need to add the ones the user chooses into an temporary array:

```
var temporarySelection = "";
var placeSelection = "";
var hotelSelection = "";
var restaurantSelections = "";
var sightSelections = "";

function chooseSelection(resultIndex) {

    var locationName = document.getElementById('locationName-' + resultIndex);

    temporarySelection += `<div class="input-group" id="Hotel-chosen">
                               <li class="list-group-item"> 
                           <strong>${locationName.innerHTML}</strong><br>`;

    var locationRating = document.getElementById('locationRating-' + 
    resultIndex);

    temporarySelection += `rating: ${locationRating.innerHTML}</li></div>`
```

}

Lastly, I need to move the temporary selection into ANOTHER array.

My problem is that, at the moment, the checkboxes are just working like buttons. Every time you click it, it just adds another one to the array. I want to only add the ones to the array that are ticked when the Next button is clicked (not shown in the code).

Any advice?

Comment: You can use `:checked` with `querySelectorAll`. Then you can select all checked checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gaslan, where abouts would I put the querySelectorAll to achieve this?